# How to extract img disk image from zip file, write to disk and show detailed progress?

Tags: dd, pv

How to show detailed progress and write disk image directly from zip file? See following tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Everyone knows that dd command does not show progress very well. Here is guide how to show detailed progress with pv and write image directly from zip file:

This method will show you the progress of writing the unzipped contents to a disk. We'll use a generic name file.zip for the zip file.

**Bash Shell:**

Install pv:
pv (Pipe Viewer) is a tool for monitoring the progress of data through a pipeline.

```
sudo apt-get install pv
```

Check the Unzipped Size:
Find out the size of the unzipped content.

```
unzip -l file.zip
```

Write to Disk:

Now, pipe the unzipped content to dd with a progress indicator.

```
unzip -p file.zip | pv -s $(unzip -l file.zip | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n 1) | sudo dd of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=4M
```

**Fish Shell:**

Install pv:

```
sudo apt-get install pv
```

Check the Unzipped Size:

```
unzip -l file.zip
```

Write to Disk:
In Fish shell, command substitution is done with parentheses ().

```
unzip -p file.zip | pv -s (unzip -l file.zip | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n 1) | sudo dd of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=4M
```

In these commands:

unzip -p file.zip unzips the file and outputs the content to stdout.
pv -s SIZE shows the progress. We obtain SIZE by running unzip -l file.zip which lists the contents of the zip file and then use awk and tail to extract the size of the unzipped content.
sudo dd of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=4M writes the unzipped content to the disk /dev/mmcblk0 with a block size of 4M.
Make sure to replace /dev/mmcblk0 with the actual path to your disk and adjust the block size bs accordingly if necessary.